# React and stateless components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I saw this comment from [React Stateless Functional Components: Nine Wins You Might Have Overlooked](https://medium.com/@housecor/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc#.18eyvtwu1):

> You should really avoid having function allocations inside statelless components. Just keep them outisde the scope and pass the props, it’s a very big performance difference.

I was wondering, if this is my component:

```
const Text = (props) =>  <p>{props.children}</p>;

// ReactDOM is part of the introduction of React 0.14
ReactDOM.render(
    <Text>Hello World</Text>, 
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

How do I access functions outside this file? Which property should I use?

Comment: It means you should not declare functions inside your stateles component-function because these functions will be created at every render. You should pass them at props

Comment: Could you give me an example or maybe send a link where I can check that out

Comment: answered with bad code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass them as a prop.

```
function clickParagraph() {
  console.log('clicked!')
}

const Text = (props) =>
  <p onClick={props.onClick}>{props.children}</p>;


ReactDOM.render(
  <Text onClick={clickParagraph}>Hello World</Text>, 
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Don't do like this:

```
const Component = (props) => {
    const getSomeResult = () => "it will be created at every render, you should pass this function in props";

    return <p>{getSomeResult()}</p>
}
```